# positiong div according to its placing order issue

Tags: html, css

I want to position divs according their placing order but they are not following each other. I want second div follow first div right after it(downwards).

```
<body>
<div id="first" style="display:block;width:20%;height:100px;position:relative;top:50px;border:2px solid green;">
</div>
<div id="second" style="background-color:lightgrey;position:relative;display:block;width:20%;height:30px;border:1px solid red;">
    <div style="position:relative;display:block;">
    Hello!
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply should delete the `position:relative` style in your **first** of your divs.

```
<body>
<div id="first" style="display:block;width:20%;height:100px;top:50px;border:2px solid green;">
</div>
<div id="second" style="background-color:lightgrey;position:relative;display:block;width:20%;height:30px;border:1px solid red;">
    <div style="position:relative;display:block;">
    Hello!
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
```

Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/dnvabqgx/1/

## Why do `position:relative` matters

This type of positioning is probably the most confusing and misused. What it really means is "relative to itself".

If you set `position: relative;` on an element but no other positioning attributes (top, left, bottom or right), it will no effect on it's positioning at all, it will be exactly as it would be if you left it as `position: static;`

But if you **DO** give it some other positioning attribute, say, `top: 50p;` *as you don in your first div,* **it will shift it's position 50 pixels DOWN from where it would NORMALLY be.**

*--read about all the position properties [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)*

Comment: @GeorgeGkas why the user has to accept the answer first to know why position:relative matters?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question of 'why position:relative matters?'; position relative moves an element into normal flow, allowing it to be positioned on the web page using the offset properties like top, right, bottom and down.